# How is this JavaScript object created for this bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, object, bookmarklet, casperjs

I am trying to reverse engineer a bookmarklet that uses CasperJS.

It creates an object called `__utils__` that I can execute console commands with.

The link to the bookmarklet is here:-

http://casperjs.org/api.html#bookmarklet

Which references this JavaScript file:-

https://raw.github.com/n1k0/casperjs/master/modules/clientutils.js

I have searched through the whole source code and I cannot find a reference to how this object is created.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bookmarklet simply runs a small snippet of JavaScript code that appends a link to the clientutils.js to the document's end. After that, it will run an anonymous function every 50 milliseconds that checks if the script has loaded (and has made the `ClientUtils` function available), and if it has, it stops running the function and creates `window.__utils__`, thus making it available in the console. Here's the actual bookmarklet code in a more readable format. It should be pretty straightforward to understand:

```
(function () {
  void(function () {
    if (!document.getElementById('CasperUtils')) {
      var CasperUtils = document.createElement('script');
      CasperUtils.id = 'CasperUtils';
      CasperUtils.src = 'https://raw.github.com/n1k0/casperjs/master/modules/clientutils.js';
      document.documentElement.appendChild(CasperUtils);
      var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof ClientUtils === 'function') {
          window.__utils__ = new window.ClientUtils();
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 50);
    }
  }());
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I overlooked the second part of the bookmarklet function.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of `api.html`. After `Just drag this link` look at the JS in the `href` attribute. Near the end it contains:

```
window.__utils__=new%20window.clientUtils();
```